# How to use angular2 http API for tracking upload/download progress

Tags: http, angular, interceptor, angular2-http

Thus there are many ad hoc libraries supporting upload/download progress in angular2, I do not know how to use native angular2 http api to show progress while doing upload/download.

The reason why I want to use native http api is because I want to utilize:

1. http interceptors (http API wrappers) around native http api that validate, cache & enrich the actual http request being sent such as [this](https://github.com/1tontech/ngx-http-interceptor/tree/angular2) & [this](https://github.com/voliva/angular2-interceptors)
2. Angular's http api is much more robust than any ad hoc APIs

There is [a nice article](http://restlet.com/blog/2016/08/29/whats-new-in-the-http-module-of-angular-2/) about how to do upload/download using angular's http api

But the article mentions that there is no native way to support progress.

Did anyone try using http api for showing progress?

If not, do you know an issue in the angular repo for this?

Comment: Someone requested for closure of this question saying its too broad. Well, its not.

Did anyone use angular's http api to track progress?. Any generic Http API is supposed to be used in this context. Its as specific as a question can get.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**As of Angular 4.3.x and beyond versions**, it can be achieved using the new [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) from `@angular/common/http`.

Read the [Listening to progress events](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events) section.

Simple upload example (copied from the section mentioned above):

```js
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/upload/file', file, {
      reportProgress: true,
    });

    http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
      // Via this API, you get access to the raw event stream.
      // Look for upload progress events.
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        // This is an upload progress event. Compute and show the % done:
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`);
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
      }
    });
```

And for downloading, it might be something like pretty much the same:

```js
    const req = new HttpRequest('GET', '/download/file', {
      reportProgress: true,
    });

    http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
      // Via this API, you get access to the raw event stream.
      // Look for download progress events.
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
        // This is an download progress event. Compute and show the % done:
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% downloaded.`);
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('File is completely downloaded!');
      }
    });
```

Remember in case that you're monitoring a download, the `Content-Length` has to be set, otherwise, there's no way to the request to be measured.

Comment: Worked for me on 4.1.x as well

Comment: R u sure it was 4.1.x? Not only in `package.json` but the fetched was above?

Comment: Hi i am getting event.total as undefined not sure why ?

Comment: @slartidan `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

`constructor(private http: HttpClient)`

Comment: I can add that when using Angular `7.2.4`, I needed both `reportProgress: true` and `observe: 'events'` to actually see the progress events. Only `observe: 'events'` will not do download/upload progress events, and leaving out `observe` will default to `observe: 'body'` which only returns the body of the response and no other events.

Comment: By giving method,when download progress, I could not get the event.total , only the event.loaded is defined

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the native JavaScript XHR wrapped as an Observable, it's fairly easy to create on your own:

```
upload(file: File): Observable<string | number> {

    let fd: FormData = new FormData();

    fd.append("file", file);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

    return Observable.create(observer => {

        xhr.addEventListener("progress", (progress) => {

            let percentCompleted;

            // Checks if we can really track the progress
            if (progress.lengthComputable) {

                // progress.loaded is a number between 0 and 1, so we'll multiple it by 100
                percentCompleted = Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100);

                if (percentCompleted < 1) {
                    observer.next(0);
                } else {
                    // Emit the progress percentage
                    observer.next(percentCompleted);
                }
            }
        });

        xhr.addEventListener("load", (e) => {

            if (e.target['status'] !== 200) observer.error(e.target['responseText']);

            else observer.complete(e.target['responseText']);
        });

        xhr.addEventListener("error", (err) => {

            console.log('upload error', err);

            observer.error('Upload error');
        });

        xhr.addEventListener("abort", (abort) => {

            console.log('upload abort', abort);

            observer.error('Transfer aborted by the user');
        });

        xhr.open('POST', 'http://some-dummy-url.com/v1/media/files');

        // Add any headers if necessary
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer rqrwrewrqe`);

        // Send off the file
        xhr.send(fd);

        // This function will get executed once the subscription
        // has been unsubscribed
        return () => xhr.abort()
    });
}
```

And this is how one would use it:

```
// file is an instance of File that you need to retrieve from input[type="file"] element
const uploadSubscription = this.upload(file).subscribe(progress => {
    if (typeof progress === Number) {
        console.log("upload progress:", progress);
    }
});

// To abort the upload
// we should check whether the subscription is still active
if (uploadSubscription) uploadSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Writing my own version is something I want to avoid & I have mentioned why that is the case in the question

Comment: For eg., your example does not handle unsubscriptions at all. Along with that I will lose interception capabilities that validates & enriches the request in various way before the request is sent

Comment: You don't need to unsubscribe from my code sample. We call either `complete` or `error` in all of the `XHR` events, these will unsubscribe automatically. Please elaborate on what you mean with validating and enriching the the request. Angular's http doesn't provide this at the moment, look at https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/src/static_response.ts#L73. There is `bytesLoaded` and `totalBytes` but this has not been used anywhere yet.

Comment: Just look at this. https://github.com/1tontech/x-ng2-http-interceptor-demo

Comment: w.r.t complete/error, if the user clicks on a different tab while the request is being sent (its possible an appication to have this behaviour to be natual), the user can be asked a prompt to cancel the existing request and move on to the clicked page. In this case, you would need unsubscribe

Comment: @Kalinga you are[were] right. I came across this issue today, I updated my answer to add an "abort" functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible, check out https://angular.io/guide/http#tracking-and-showing-request-progress.

I could give an example here but I think that the official example from the Angular docs would be better