# there is upload time mismatch between server and client?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am uploading files/folder on server. and tracking progress with HttpEventType on client side to show progress but it showing file upload completed even all file has not been uploaded on server. and after some time there is response from server of success.

```
fileUpload(event: any) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
    this.api.uploadFiles(this.files).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

```
uploadFiles(file:FileList){
    const formData:FormData =new FormData();
    formData.append("key","name")
    for(let i=0;i<file.length;i++){
       formData.append("files",file[i]);
    }
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST',fileUploadPath, formData, {
      reportProgress: true
    });
    return this.http.request(req).pipe(
      
      map(res =>{
          if (res.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            const percentDone = Math.round(100 * res.loaded / (res.total ?? 0));
            this.loader.progressValue=percentDone;
          }
          if(res.type==HttpEventType.Response){
            this.loader.displayProgress=false;
          }
          return res;
      }),
      catchError((err):any=>{this.error.handleError(err);return err})
    );
  }
```

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45222419/14973743) method using the `subscribe` on the http request?

Comment: Refer the angular official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#tracking-and-showing-request-progress) for the handling of progress event for file upload.

Comment: I tried using subscribe, also followed same in documentation but still that issue persist.

Comment: Can you post the latest code snippet that you tried with. the one pasted in your question right now deviates much from the example given in the angular documentation.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran
I have edited the, have a look , what is the problem.